# What are the rules for linking translation units in C11?

Tags: c, linker, c11

The C11 standards talk about the linkage of identifiers, but there is no obvious discussion about the rules of linking translation units. My question is brought up by compiling two simple examples using clang.

Here is my first example, which has two declarations of the same function but with incompatible types:

```
//testall.c
extern char myfun(void*);

int main(){
  char a='c';
  a=myfun(&a);
}

char myfun(char*c){
  return *c;
}
```

Then I run the command: $clang -std=c11 testall.c
And clang reports an error:

> testall.c:9:10: error: conflicting types for 'myfun'
>       char myfun(char*c){
>       ^
>   testall.c:2:17: note: previous declaration is here
>       extern char myfun(void*);
>           ^
>   1 error generated.

I understand this error, because the void pointer and pointer to char are incompatible types.
What confuses me is that when I separate the two declarations into two different translation units and then link them into one, clang doesn't report any error:

```
//test.c
extern char myfun(void*);

int main(){
  char a='c';
  a=myfun(&a);
}

// mylib.c
char myfun(char*c){
  return *c;
}
```

Then I run this command: $clang -std=c11 test.c mylib.c.
clang compiles and links the two translation units without reporting any error or warning.

I was thinking that linking two translation units follows the rules in section 6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers of the C11 standards. But it seems that it is not the case. Can anyone help me to clarify it?

Comment: Just because you don't get a diagnostic doesn't mean the code is legal!  Traditionally, a compiler looks at just one translation unit at a time (so it couldn't detect the mismatch when compiling), and type information isn't passed into the object file, so the linker won't be able to detect the mismatch either.

Comment: @NateEldredge Try doing one file at a time instead of specifying both at the command line. Doing `gcc a.c b.c` does compile and link in one step. C doesn't do name mangling so the names of the function look exactly the same to the linker. Now what if you have three object files all with `myfun`? You'll get a function redefinition error. So clearly what you said can't be true.

Comment: Although `gcc a.c b.c` runs both the compiler and linker, they are two separate passes that don't share information other than the object file.  The linker is able to detect multiple **definitions** of the same symbol.  But in your example, the function `myfun` is only **defined** once, in `mylib.c`.  The file `test.c` contains a **declaration** of `myfun` but no **definition**.  Hence no error from the linker.

Comment: This boils down to that any C program that does not present a function prototype before the function is called is very poorly-written. Similarly, any C program where the function prototype and definition are different, is very poorly written. Just don't write bad code and you will get no such problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, we are building a tool to analysis C programs according to the C11 standards. We found such problems in some programs in practice. And we need to figure out what is the "right" way according to the C11 standards to deal with such issue. If it is undefined behavior, then the tool will report an error; if it is implementation-dependent, then we may choose the way that clang does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example with two separate files, the behavior is undefined.  Here is my “case”, based on the C11 Standard:

C11 6.2.2(4):

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern ...
>   If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior
>   declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external
>   linkage.

In `test.c`, `myfun` has external linkage because it is declared with `extern` and no prior declaration is visible.

C11 6.2.2(5):

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class
>   specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with
>   the storage-class specifier extern.

In `mylib.c`, `myfun` is declared with no storage-class specifier, therefore it is as if it were declared with `extern`, therefore it has external linkage in this translation unit as well.

C11 6.9.1.(7) [function definitions]:

> If the declarator includes a parameter type list, the list also
>   specifies the types of all the parameters; such a declarator also
>   serves as a function prototype for later calls to the same function
>   in the same translation unit

Hence the definition of `myfun` in `mylib.c` is also a declaration of `myfun` (in case you had any doubts).

C11 6.2.2(2):

> In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an
>   entire program, each declaration of a particular identifier with
>   external linkage denotes the same object or function.

Therefore the two `myfun`s denote the same function.

C11 6.2.7(2):

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall
>   have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The two declarations of `myfun` have incompatible types (I could show
that if you want, but it’s why Clang complained in the single-file
case.)  Therefore the behavior of the whole program is undefined.

Note that 6.2.7(2) is not a *constraint*, therefore Clang is not
required to issue a diagnostic when it is violated.  However,
in the single file case, there is an actual constraint violation,
as the following occurs under the heading "Constraints":

C11 6.7(4):

> All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object
>   or function shall specify compatible types.

So Clang must issue the diagnostic in that case.

Answer (score 3):

This is just *undefined behaviour*. C11 doesn't say anything about *linkers* or how they combine multiple translation units. In practice, this is not an issue since there would be a header file with function declaration for `myfun()` that's included the both of those C files.

Comment: Does your "undefined behaviour" mean that anything could happen like the C11 standards? Or you mean that linkers are just out of the scope of the C11 standards?

Comment: I mean the former and the latter is also true. Basically, linkers (at least the Unix and GNU linkers I have used) don't do any type checking. So a diagnostic is not easy. But in your particular example, it will also work as expected pretty much on all systems as `char*` and `void*` are required to have the same representation.